# Anaconda Python: Cannot execute native linux-32 binary

Tags: python, debian, anaconda, 32-bit, odroid

I get the following error while installing Anaconda Python on an Odroid XU4.

```
installing: conda-env-2.4.5-py27_0 ...
Anaconda2-4.0.0-Linux-x86.sh: line 460: /root/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
ERROR:
cannot execute native linux-32 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux odroid-jessie 3.10.92+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 3 11:23:35 CET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run an `x86` installer on an `armv7l` device.

To fix this, you should download the correct installer for your device's platform.

[This post on the official developers' blog](https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-support-raspberry-pi-2-and-power8-le) offers useful information about installing Anaconda on `armv7l` devices, and provides the following installer links:

[armv7l (Python 2)](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh)

[armv7l (Python 3)](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of those installers.